# Slow query on update using select count(*)

Tags: mysql, performance, select, count, indexing

I have to count how many times a number from table2 occurs between the number in range table2.a and table2.b

i.e. we wanna know how many times we have this : a < start < b

I ran the following query :

```
UPDATE table2
 SET occurrence =  
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE start BETWEEN table2.a AND table2.b);



table2 
ID   a   b    occurrence
1    1   10
2    1   20
3    1   25
4    2   30


table1 
ID start col1 col2 col3
1   1
2   7
3  10
4  21
5  25
6  27
7  30
```

table2 as

- 3 indexes on a, b and occurrence
- 1567 rows (so we will SELECT COUNT(*) over table2 1567 times..)
- ID column as PK

table1 as

- 1 index on start
- 42,000,000 rows
- Column start was "ordered by column start"
- ID column as PK

==> it took 2.5hours to do 2/3 of it. I need to speed this up... any suggestions ? :)

Comment: Have you tried `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` on the query?

Comment: yes but it doesn't tell me much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add the id column to the index on table 1:

```
CREATE INDEX start_index ON table1 (start,id);
```

And rewrite the query to

```
UPDATE table2
 SET occurrence =  
       (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1 WHERE start BETWEEN table2.a AND table2.b);
```

This is called "covering index": http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/

-> The whole query on table 1 can be served through the data in the index -> no additional page lookup for the actual record.

Answer (score 1):

Use a stored procedure. Keep the result from COUNT in a local variable, then use it to run the UPDATE query.

Answer (score 0):

I will do this

```
// use one expensive join
create table tmp
select table2.id, count(*) as occurrence 
from table1
inner join table1
on table1.start between table2.a and table2.b
group by table1.id;

update table2, tmp
set table2.occurrence=tmp.occurrence 
where table2.id=tmp.id;
```

Comment: I have no measurement on this, you can post the explain plan of the SELECT statement. Then we can further discuss on that

Comment: Should it not be table1.start instead of table1.id? The approach is promising!

Comment: You switched table1 and table2?

Answer (score -1):

I think count(*) makes the database read the data rows when in your case it only needs to read the index. Try:

```
UPDATE table2
 SET occurrence =  
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 WHERE start BETWEEN table2.a AND table2.b);
```

Comment: Thanks I tried and it took the whole night to update just one table.. I'm not sure this is the best way to go~

Comment: Same performance and explain plan as count(*)? In that case I guess the optimiser is smart enough to just read the index in both cases.